# How to create folder using the id from url path in spring mvc? i have created folder but i want to create using id from upload.html?

Tags: java

I am new spring boot. My task is to create folder.

This is controller code. I have created folder but want to create using id? And add multiple files and delete them.

```
  @Controller
    public class UploadController {

    //Save the uploaded file to this folder
    private static String UPLOADED_FOLDER = "E://temp//";

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "upload";
    }

    @PostMapping("/upload") // //new annotation since 4.3
    public String singleFileUpload(@RequestParam("id") Long id,
                                   @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                                   RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

        if (file.isEmpty()) {
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Please select a file to upload");
            return "redirect:uploadStatus";
        }


        try
        {
            Long userId;
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
            String filename =file.getOriginalFilename();
            int pos=filename.lastIndexOf(".");
            System.out.println(pos);
            if (pos>0)
            {
                filename=filename.substring(0, pos);
            }
            System.out.println(filename);
            File folder=new File("E:\\temp\\"+filename+"\\");
            System.out.println(folder);
            folder.mkdirs();


            Path path = Paths.get("E:\\temp\\"+filename+"\\"+ file.getOriginalFilename());
            System.out.println(UPLOADED_FOLDER);
            Files.write(path, bytes);




            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message",
                    "You successfully uploaded '" + file.getOriginalFilename() + "'");
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "redirect:/uploadStatus";
        }
```

This my Html code upload.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<body>

<h1>Spring Boot file upload example</h1>

<form method="POST" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" /><br/><br/>
    <input typr="text" name="id" /><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File file = new File("C:\\Directory1");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            if (file.mkdir()) {
                System.out.println("Directory is created!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed to create directory!");
            }
        }
```

Above code will make directory for you. Append you id in Path will make directory with your " id ".

Comment: hello rahul, how to get id , i am blocked here. Should i create object to that id

Comment: So your question is **@RequestParam("id")** Long id is not working ??

Comment: Yes, should i create an object to access that id. if yes, then how

Comment: s, should i create object to get that id, if yes than how. I am suppose create folder with that id and store files in it and delete particular file

Comment: Probably you can try @RequestPart for the ID along with your multipart file parameter.